# Possible to have an ID (auto incremented) as the second column of a MySQL primary key?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have an `id` (auto incremented) as the second column of a MySQL primary key? see `order` table below.

My idea is that it would be faster for MySQL to access `orders` through the primary key index (customer_id, id) when I query the `order` table with `customer_id`.Thanks

```
  Customer
+-------------+
| id (autoinc)| --> primary key
|- - - - - - -|
| name        |
| address     |
+-------------+
       |
       |
       |
       A
  Order     
+------------------+        
| customer_id (fk) | --- primary key
| id     (autoinc) | --- primary key        
|- - - - - - - - - |
| date             |
+------------------+
```

Comment: Depends on the database engine used for the table, in some like InnoDB it will help by storing the records close together, but it sounds like a  (probably premature) optimization to me; you're just as, if not more, likely to benefit from a `when, id` PK (though that could probably be seen as redundant.)

Comment: I've worked on DB2, and most of the time, for performance, it was done like the `order` table above, since we would query the order table with only the `customer_id` in hand, 99% of the time. But of course, this makes a difference with high volumes. I'm guessing MySQL does it differently, or maybe it automatically creates an index for the `customer_id` foreign key?

Comment: Yeah, all FK fields must be indexed (or start an index) on both sides of the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the answer from gr1zzly be4r...

InnoDB actually allows you to use an auto-increment as the first column of any KEY, not necessarily just a UNIQUE KEY.

```
CREATE TABLE `your_table` (
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`,`b`),
  KEY `b` (`b`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO your_table (a) VALUES (42), (43);
SELECT * FROM your_table;
+----+---+
| a  | b |
+----+---+
| 42 | 1 |
| 43 | 2 |
+----+---+
```

In other words, the `b` column doesn't necessarily need to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following table syntax, but I'm not really sure what performance benefit that you're going to get. I'll look into it and update my answer.

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (a INT NOT NULL, b INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE);
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (a, b);
```

But, you can't drop the `UNIQUE` key on b.

Comment: Thanks @gr1zzlybe4r, is it possible that MySQL (InnoDB) would automatically create an index for the foreign key above `customer_id` in the order table, plus another index for the `id` auto increment column? If that's the case (having two indexes, one for each column) is almost the same (performance wise) as one index with both columns (`customer_id, id`) in it.

Comment: @user3489502, a query will have much better performance if it uses a single index. Technically MySQL has an "index merge" optimization to use two indexes from the same table, but it doesn't work very well in my experience.

Comment: @BillKarwin, thanks for the information. So with the two indexes, the performance issues would be noticed on inserts when MySQL writes to the table, plus the two indexes? or on selects e.g `select * from order where customer_id = x;` Would this query use only one index (the one created for the foreign key `customer_id`)? Thanks!

Comment: @user3489502 In the table you showed, the `FOREIGN KEY` doesn't need to create another index if there's already an index on `customer_id`, including the primary key index. So your primary key index and your foreign key index will be the same index (i.e. the clustered index).